# Can't connect to internet on ec2 windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I am trying to spin up a ec2 windows server in a private VPC, but I am unable to connect with internet. I have already read all the documents and posts on internet, so far I have done:

1. Checked my ec2 has public IP address
2. It is in public subnet and public subnet has route table that got entry to internet and destination is internet gateway.
3. Internet gateway is attached to VPC.
4. Security group and NCL also have allow rule for HTTP.
   But still when I am accessing server through remote in, I couldn't see internet connection symbol to left and couldn't connect to internet.

Outbound Config for security group is:

All traffic All port and protocol and destination is 0.0.0.0/0.

I am not sure what else I should do?

Thanks in advance
AF

Troubleshooting, checking all the network settings

Comment: What is the error message? Does it take a long time to fail, or does it take some time (eg 10 seconds)? How are you trying to "connect" to it (RDP, SSH, HTTP)? Are you able to connect to _other_ EC2 instances? Have you tried from a different network (eg home vs office vs tethering via phone), just to make sure it isn't blocked by your corporate network?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply. I got remote into the system and trying to access the internet. It is showing no internet connection icon into the system.

Comment: Are you saying that, from a computer outside of AWS, you are able to RDP directly into the Windows system? If so, then most of the network settings seem good! Please edit your question to show the Outbound configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance. What happens when you run `ping 8.8.8.8` in the Command Prompt?

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, for insanely late reply. When I am doing ping 8.8.8.8, I am getting reply but for some reason I am not able to browse internet in the system (EC2 instance).

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to browse"? What error message are you receiving? If you are trying to use Internet Explorer, then you need to turn off IEC. See: [Disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration in Windows Server 2019](https://medium.com/tensult/disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-in-windows-server-2019-a9cf5528be65)

Comment: Hey John,

I tried it, still no luck. I am not getting any error, it's just showing "Can't reach this page" on the browser. I am assuming for some reason, I don't have internet connection working on EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root cause of the problem, it was happening because there is DNS setup locally for my organisation, all instances residing inside the VPC have been allocated that DNS server and that DNS server is blocking the internet connection.

Thanks for your help

Ali